# Black screen issue,compiling with cocoonjs

Tags: javascript, android, createjs, cocoonjs

I am compiling createjs game through cloud services of ludei. But when I paste the zip generated from cloud to my android phone sd card ,and run it from cooonjs launcher ,app shows black screen with fps.When i clicked FPS it says could not find index file or js html file .
What should i do now to run my app on cocconjs launcher?

My folder structure inside zip which i submitted to cloud is like

```
     (index.html,java scripts(folder),images(folder).
```

Comment: Update: I have downloaded the demo from cocoon's website.Then got the compiled zip,shifted to Sd card ,ran the zip ,still the same issue.        P.S i want to post this issue on cocoon forum ,but when i do it says "NO permission"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i uploaded the zip file (with index.html ) to my sd card of phone.Run the cocoon app from phone ,gave the path of zip file and bingo.Application Ran.!    "conclusion"You don't need cloud services of ludei for testing :)

Comment: This isn't really an answer, you cannot use the launcher app to build a release apk.